# Javascript regular expression "exec" method: memoizing bug / effect

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Take the following code and execute it:

```js
str1 = 'foobar\nFooBar';
str2 = 'FooBar\nfoobar';
r = /foo/gi;
res1 = r.exec(str1);
res2 = r.exec(str2);
console.log(res1, res2);
```

What I would expect is `foo` and `Foo`. What you get is `foo` and `foo`.

The explanation is that when `exec` is called with modifier `g` it will remember the position it found the last match at and continue from there on subsequent calls. This is meant as feature for calling it multiple times on the **same** string. However I cannot see any possible scenario where one would want to continue on that position when called on a **new** string. Imho this is a bug or at least a serious flaw. Is it?

EDIT: is there any JS spec requiring the regex object **not** to maintain a separate match index for each different string object / char sequence?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. The regex doesn't know if it's getting the same string or not.

Comment: That does not make it "not a bug". It is possible and common to code memoising functions using hash tables to match the input to a memoised result. New input, new result.

Comment: I didn't say that makes it not a bug. I'm just telling you that it's not one.  Anyway, if it did use memoization, would it be on the string's reference or its value? What if you give it a different reference to a new string with the same characters? Is that a new string? What if you add new content to the string and want to continue where you left off? No matter what, there's going to be some behavior that breaks expectations. The object simply takes its input and behaves in the simplest manner. Its state is tied only to its calls, irrespective of the input.

Comment: I understand what `exec` does. And I think it is counter intuitive to an extent that makes it a bug. Regarding your remarks: of course it should hash the string chars. That's it. Strings are immutable in JS so if you manipulate them you always create new strings which would also make it possible to hash the memory pointer - possible but counter intuitive.

Comment: You're missing the point. Yes, strings are immutable, but imagine a situation where a string is being parsed while doing some other manipulation on it. From the perspective of that user, they would want to continue working on it as though it was the same input. Then take the user who is running `exec()` on a list of strings, some of which may match. Suddenly some of the matches seem to be starting from arbitrary points. This is a no-win situation, so the regex object relies on its own state.

Comment: WRT it being a bug, maybe you could argue that it's a "design flaw", but it's not a bug, because that's not a matter of opinion. The object is behaving correctly as required by the spec.

Comment: You can reset the `.lastIndex` of the regex object to the index from which you want the next call to start. With that, you could just create your own "improved" object that wraps the regex object and resets the `r.lastIndex` under whatever conditions you want. Otherwise, string methods don't regard the state of the regex object, so you can use those if you prefer.

Comment: Nice one! Resetting lastIndex seems like a good option to me, might do my own wrapper. Thanks, good point!

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behavior, as indicated by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) (emphasis mine):

> If the match succeeds, the `exec()` method returns an array and **updates properties of the regular expression object**. The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured.

This behavior is a property of the regex *object*, not the regex *engine*. You can see the difference by not using a regex object:

```js
str1 = 'foobar\nFooBar';
str2 = 'FooBar\nfoobar';
r = /foo/gi;
res1 = r.exec(str1);
res2 = r.exec(str2);
console.log(res1, res2);

// No object
console.log(/foo/gi.exec(str1));
console.log(/foo/gi.exec(str2));
```

Comment: Good point regarding the flaw being part of the JS object, not the regex implementation, did not realize that! I still think that this makes no sense and that the regex object should maintain an index for each char sequence / each reference. The spec you cite does not imply that this should not be the case. Good points, thanks.